# Run nodejs script with 100% cpu

Tags: node.js

I'd like to run my nodejs script with 100% cpu usage. How can I achieve this?

I want to do some calculations really fast and I think with more cpu usage it will run faster.

It is stuck at 15% cpu usage.

Comment: What are your calculations ? Everything depend on this, your could be in a car at first gear, your engine will work at 100% capacity but you will be going at 10km/h

Comment: If it's stuck at 15% CPU usage your calculation simply doesn't require 100% CPU usage.

Comment: my program calculates collatze sequence numbers @JeanJacquesGourdin

Comment: Does your program runs for a long time ? Does is stays at 15% all the time ? How many cores do you have the processor of your machine ?

Comment: @robertklep I suspect OP is simply misreading the usage. Which itself can be misleading. Depending on the tool, 100% might mean *all* available cores at full usage. So, if one core is used at maximum, that will be just a portion of the 100% - 15% is *likely* one core out of six being used at full capacity and likely a portion of the other core(s).

Comment: @JeanJacquesGourdin I have 6 cores, and it does stay at 15% all the time.

Comment: More CPU usage does not in any way equate to some process running faster. It is also not an accurate metric in terms of what is reported to Windows in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is single threaded, it can only run in a single core of your processor.

Your JS process currently uses 100% of a core, hence, 15% (1/6) of your total computational power.

You need to do parallel computations with cluster module to use all your processor power.

This can be very tricky to do efficiently because you will need a common memory between processes to avoid useless computations.

If you want to do it, the easiest way is to have the primary process giving await numbers to workers to compute.